# Send notification to user when app full close

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

It is necessary that even after the application is completely turned off by the user, notifications come from the node server. Tried to do through Broadcastreceiver and Service, but they only output if the app is in the background. I'm considering The firebase messages option, but I can't fully understand if it will work when the application is completely turned off. If there are options as it is possible to make it on another, prompt, please, in what direction to go.

Answer (score 1):

When the user did not force stop(Settings -> app -> Force stop) the app, [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) will work.

> It means, Firebase Cloud Messaging will work after user close the app
>   normally

Comment: This is the only answer that's considered good. The other ones, like frequently polling the server is just a waste of device resources.